# how to create a global array in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a global array so that these functions fib() and shoot() can share it.
Here is my code:

```
global f
f=[0]*1000
def fib(n):

    f[0]=1  ## error here  
    f[1]=1
    for i in xrange(2,n+1):
        f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]

def shoot(aliens):
    ...
    place to use f[] here

fib(999)
print shoot(line)
```

however it shows an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  line 56, in <module>
fib(999)
line 42, in fib
f[0]=1
TypeError: 'file' object does not support item assignment
```

please help!

Edit: Comments below made me realise that I had "with open('somefile') as f" in another part of my code not shown here. I removed that, and now, it's working.

Comment: "line 42, in fib" Is there more you're not showing us?

Comment: You already have a variable called `f` which is a file.

Comment: @Haidro that's all It has. I Just copied it directly to here.

Comment: @TungPham I highly doubt it. You probably overrode your list `f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrode your list `f` with:

```
with open(...) as f:
```

You can either:

- Rename the list
- Change the name of the file (i.e, something like `as myfile`)

Because this happened, you're then trying to access the list with indexing, but you're actually working with a file object. This is why you get a `TypeError: 'file' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 0):

Just move the line `global f` into your functions:

```
f=[0]*1000
def fib(n):
    global f

    f[0]=1  ## error here  
    f[1]=1
    for i in xrange(2,n+1):
        f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]

def shoot(aliens):
    ...
    global f
    ... do stuff with f here ...
```

Or alternatively, pass `f` in as a parameter to the functions:

```
def fib(n, f):
    ...

def shoot(aliens, f):
    ...
```

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't explain the error. Infact, his current code should work fine

Comment: @haidro oh yeah - you're right! I didn't look at that. Do you think there is a `with open('somefile') as f` somewhere higher in the program?

Comment: @TungPham what happens if you rename your array to something else, like: `array_f`? Does this fix your problem?

Comment: @NickBurns OH. you're right. I have "with open('somefile') as f" in my code. now, it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the array in the beginning.

Whenever you wish to modify/access/change your arraym just use the keyword global to refer to that array.

Here is an example:

```
myarray=[]

def func():
     global myarray
     myarray[0]=1
```

Cheers!